# Not sure about proof presentation - existence of division with remainder

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Hi so I am taking an elementary number theory course and we are asked to prove the division with remainder theorem. I think I've got it, but this is my first time really writing up a proof of a 'proper' theorem by myself, even though this is a very basic result. I was hoping I could get a few pointers if I am writing in a manner that is completely terrible or non mathematical or too pedantic, etc. Apologies if this sounds like a vague question, if it needs closing that is fine.

"Prove that for any integer $a$ and given a natural number $d$ we can find integers $q$ and $r$ which are unique, so that $0 \le r < d$ and $a=qd +r$"

My attempt at a proof is as follows, I'm hoping you can critique it.

If $d > a \ge 0$ then $ a = 0.d + a$ is the only way to satisfy the conditions. Now, if $ a<0$ then $ -a > 0$ and if $0 \le r < d$ where $(-a) = qd + r$, then $a = (-q-1)d + (d-r)$ so existence and uniqueness for $a$ in only the positive or negative integers guarantees existence or uniqueness in the other case.

I thus aim to prove the following: For a given natural number $d>0$, for any natural number $a$ such that $ a \ge d > 0$ there are unique integers $q$ and $r$ such that $a=qd +r$ and $0 \le r < d$.

Let us begin by considering the set

$A = \{ n \in \mathbb{N} : a - (n+1)d <0 \}$

This set is not the empty set because it contains $a$ so we may pick it's minimum element, call it $q$.

In particular, $a-qd \ge 0$ so set $r = a - qd$. We need only show $r$ is less than $d$ because clearly $r + qd$ is equal to $a$.

Suppose not. Then $a - qd \ge d$ and so we see $ a - (q+1)d \ge 0$ a contradiction.

Finally, note that if $a = q_1.d + r_1$ and $a = q_2.d + r_2$ with $d > r_1,r_2 \ge 0$ where $r_1 > r_2$ then $d > r_1 - r_2 = d(q_2 - q_1)$

Now $r_1 - r_2$ and $d$ are greater than zero, so $(q_2 - q_1) \ge 0$. If this difference is greater than or equal to $1$ then $d(q_2 - q_1) \ge d > r_1 - r_2$ an apparent contradiction and this proves equality of $r_1$ and $r_2$.

Finally, because $\mathbb{N}$ has no zero divisors, equality is established between $q_1$ and $q_2$.

Comment: i.e. $\, S = a + d\,\Bbb Z\,$ is closed under subtraction by $d,\,$ so its least element $\,r \ge 0\,$ satisfies $\,r < d\,$ (else, by closure, $\,r\!-\!d\in S\,$ and $\,0 \le r\!-\!d < r,\,$ contra leastness of $\,r)\ \ $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof of existence looks fine; however, there's something off in your uniqueness proof. You state first that $d > r_1-r_2$, and then that $d = r_1-r_2$. I would go for a simpler argument like the following:

Suppose $a = q_1d + r_1 = q_2d+r_2$ with $q_1,q_2\geq 0$ and $d>r_1\geq r_2\geq 0$. Then $r_1-r_2 =(q_2-q_1)d \geq 0$. By choice of $r_1,r_2$, we must have $d>r_1-r_2\geq 0$, which means $d > (q_2-q_1)d \geq 0$. Dividing each side by $d$, we get $1 > q_2-q_1 \geq 0$. Since $q_1$ and $q_2$ are integers, this means $q_2-q_1 = 0$, and hence $r_1-r_2 = 0$.

Comment: Thank you very much, didn't spot that, you are right - it should be a '>' not a '=', and then we get a contradiction. However, I think you're proof is slicker, will edit the original - thanks for the feedback, still trying to get down a logical order in my proofs - still struggling but we'll make it one day haha! Always confusing how proofs appear so easy in a book but so hard when you try to write one.